# Using Python Pandas to concatenate and pull values from from every group of 3 rows into one single row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a very unstructured CSV with thousands of rows. I'm managed to get it 50% there in terms of where I want it, but struggling to transform it any further.

I don't expect a full answer, but even just if someone could point me in the right direction, or let me know if it isn't possible. I've been told by my boss I'll have to do this manually.

I want to go from this:

| Unit-Tag No. | Header | Description instrument | Manufacturer | Remarks | Supplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CYG30EU005 Shaft vibration | Header |  |  |  |  |
| VSTTH |  | Common alarm - Vibration | Vibro-Meter | hardwired (VM to PLC) | Siemens Energy |
| BC000414P01E070 |  | Unit Control panel MMS | VM600 | TEEEES |  |
| 415012 |  |  | DDD |  | VSH9020 |
| VSH |  | Common alarm - Vibration | Siemens Energy | hardwired (VM to PLC) | Siemens Energy |
| BC000414P01E070CIEIA |  | Unit Control panel PLC | WinCC/PCS7 |  |  |
| 415013 |  |  |  |  | VSH9020 |
| CYG30EU010 Shaft position | Header |  |  |  |  |
| VSH |  | Common alarm - Position | Vibro-Meter | hardwired (VM to PLC) | Siemens Energy |
| 1BC000414P01E070CIEIA |  | Unit Control panel MMS | VM600 |  |  |
| 415013 |  |  |  |  | VSH9021 |

To this:

| System | Unit Tag | Doc Number | Description | Manufacturer | Model Number | EX Number | Remarks | SE-TAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CYG30EU005 Shaft vibration | VSTTH | 415012 | Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel MMS | Vibro-Meter | VM600 | DDD | hardwired (VM to PLC) ; TEEEES | VSH9020 |
| CYG30EU005 Shaft vibration | VSH | 415013 | Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel PLC | Siemens Energy | WinCC/PCS7 |  | hardwired (VM to PLC) | VSH9020 |
| CYG30EU010 Shaft position | VSH | 415013 | Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel MMS | Vibro-Meter | VM600 |  | hardwired (VM to PLC) | VSH9021 |

**Explanation:**

The below is a snippet, but the rest follows the same structure.

For rows where the value under Header is Header, these are Systems. Everything under that System (up until the next Header) is a Component of that System.

However, components only ever take up 3 lines. So under Unit-Tag No, the first component for System CYG30EU005 Shaft Vibration is represented by the lines with VSTTH, BC000414P01E070, and 415012 under Unit-Tag No. The second component is represented by the next set of 3 lines (VSH, BC000414P01E070CIEIA, 415013).

The next System is then CYG30EU010 Shaft position which only has one component in this case.

Looking at Unit-Tag No column, the first row value for a component represents the unit tag (e.g., VSTTH). The next one down can be ignored. The one below that is the doc number (e.g., 415012).

Looking at the description column, all the values associated with a single component should be concatenated with a ";". So for the first component, this would be "Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel MMS". For the next component it would be "Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel PLC". Description text can sometimes take up 3 rows. In the below components, it's only 2.

Looking at the manufacturer column, The first row value associated with a component is the actual manufacturer (e.g., Vibro-Meter). The second row value is the Model Number (e.g., VM600). The third row value may not always exist, but if it does, it's the EX Number (e.g., DDD).

Looking at the remarks column. This should be the same as the description column, in that all values for a single component should be concatenated together. In the below example, the first components remarks should be "hardwired (VM to PLC) ; TEEEES". Again, this can sometimes take up 3 rows.

The final column I'm only looking for the SE-TAG, not the actual supplier. The SE-TAG is always the same row as the doc number. So for the first component, this would be VSH9020. The second component would be the same. The third component would be VSH9021.

Essentially, for each component, I want to see the Header/System, Unit-Tag, Doc Number, Description, Manufacturer, Model Number, EX Number, Remarks, and SE-TAG.

EDIT:

Added CSV data.

```
Unit-Tag No.,Header,Description instrument,Manufacturer,Remarks,Supplier
CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration,Header,,,,
VSTTH,,Common alarm - Vibration,Vibro-Meter,hardwired (VM to PLC),Siemens Energy
BC000414P01E070,,Unit Control panel MMS,VM600,TEEES,
415012,,,DDD,,VSH9020
VSH,,Common alarm - Vibration,Siemens Energy,hardwired (VM to PLC),Siemens Energy
BC000414P01E070CIEIA,,Unit Control panel PLC,WinCC/PCS7,,
415013,,,,,VSH9020
CYG30EU010  Shaft position,Header,,,,
VSH,,Common alarm - Position,Vibro-Meter,hardwired (VM to PLC),Siemens Energy
1BC000414P01E070CIEIA,,Unit Control panel MMS,VM600,,
415013,,,,,VSH9021
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of your csv file, ready to work (i.e. with separators in a code snippet)

Comment: Hi @LukasHestermeyer. Ok, I've added an edit at the end with the CSV data copied. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to group by `System` and `Component`:

- Create a `System` column based on `Header` and forward fill it
- Create a `Component` column using `.groupby("System")` - you can  `.cumsum()` to create a sub-group every 3 rows.

```
df["System"] = df.loc[df["Header"].notna(), "Unit-Tag No."]
df["System"] = df["System"].ffill()

groups = df.groupby("System")
df["Component"] = (groups.cumcount() % 3 == 0).cumsum().shift()

# reset the header rows back to NaN
df.loc[df["Header"] == "Header", "Component"] = float("nan")
```

```
>>> df
                   Unit-Tag No.  Header    Description instrument    Manufacturer                Remarks        Supplier                       System  Component
0   CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration  Header                       NaN             NaN                    NaN             NaN  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        NaN
1                         VSTTH     NaN  Common alarm - Vibration     Vibro-Meter  hardwired (VM to PLC)  Siemens Energy  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        1.0
2               BC000414P01E070     NaN    Unit Control panel MMS           VM600                  TEEES             NaN  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        1.0
3                        415012     NaN                       NaN             DDD                    NaN         VSH9020  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        1.0
4                           VSH     NaN  Common alarm - Vibration  Siemens Energy  hardwired (VM to PLC)  Siemens Energy  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        2.0
5          BC000414P01E070CIEIA     NaN    Unit Control panel PLC      WinCC/PCS7                    NaN             NaN  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        2.0
6                        415013     NaN                       NaN             NaN                    NaN         VSH9020  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        2.0
7    CYG30EU010  Shaft position  Header                       NaN             NaN                    NaN             NaN   CYG30EU010  Shaft position        NaN
8                           VSH     NaN   Common alarm - Position     Vibro-Meter  hardwired (VM to PLC)  Siemens Energy   CYG30EU010  Shaft position        4.0
9         1BC000414P01E070CIEIA     NaN    Unit Control panel MMS           VM600                    NaN             NaN   CYG30EU010  Shaft position        4.0
10                       415013     NaN                       NaN             NaN                    NaN         VSH9021   CYG30EU010  Shaft position        4.0
```

You can then `.groupby` system/component and `.agg` to generate your desired output:

```
# helpers to extract by "position"
first  = lambda col: col.iloc[0]
second = lambda col: col.iloc[1]
third  = lambda col: col.iloc[2]

str_concat = lambda col: " ; ".join(col[col.notna()])

df.groupby(["System", "Component"]).agg(**{
   "Unit Tag":     ("Unit-Tag No.", first),
   "Doc Number":   ("Unit-Tag No.", third),
   "Description":  ("Description instrument", str_concat),
   "Manufacturer": ("Manufacturer", first),
   "Model Number": ("Manufacturer", second),
   "EX Number":    ("Manufacturer", third),
   "Remarks":      ("Remarks",      str_concat),
   "SE-TAG":       ("Supplier",     third)
}).reset_index()
```

```
                        System  Component Unit Tag Doc Number                                        Description    Manufacturer Model Number EX Number                        Remarks   SE-TAG
0  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        1.0    VSTTH     415012  Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel MMS     Vibro-Meter        VM600       DDD  hardwired (VM to PLC) ; TEEES  VSH9020
1  CYG30EU005  Shaft vibration        2.0      VSH     415013  Common alarm - Vibration ; Unit Control panel PLC  Siemens Energy   WinCC/PCS7       NaN          hardwired (VM to PLC)  VSH9020
2   CYG30EU010  Shaft position        4.0      VSH     415013   Common alarm - Position ; Unit Control panel MMS     Vibro-Meter        VM600       NaN          hardwired (VM to PLC)  VSH9021
```

Comment: Thanks! I've ran it on my master dataset. So far so good! This has saved me so much time. Will mark yours as the correct solution once I've ran some spot checks.